# SQLMap extracts weird chars in one column

Tags: sql-injection, tools

I saw this behaviour many times but I never solved it. Sometimes using sqlmap after retrieving good data from columns it fails retrieving only one of them. I can't figure out why this happens for just one of the columns.

This is an output sample:

```
+-------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| login       | pwdlogin                                         |
+-------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| TEST_USER   | ?\xa4\xd4\xc2??~?\xabccgq                        |
| TEST_USER   | ?\xc7\xd6\xc4???\x8f\xa4?\xa6\xaa\x9d\xb9?\xa5?b |
| TEST_USER   | ?\xc2\xe1\xae?\xa3\xa4?\xa9?t?k}?\xa3            |
| TEST_USER2  | ?\xc2\xda\xc2\xa0?\xa4`idknly?                   |
| TEST_USER3  | ?\xa2\xc1\xa6~y?u\xaa?\xa6                       |
| TEST_USER4  | ?\xa2\xb2\xb4??~?\xab`chj{?\xa5?                 |
| TEST_USER5  | ?\xa2\xb2\xb4??~?\xab`chj{?\xa5?                 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Regards.

Comment: What are the correct values for that column?

Comment: @Slicedpan Should be a plain text password

Comment: Do the pws for TEST_USER4 and TEST_USER5 match?

Comment: @Slicedpan Yes, it's a test database. If I try to retrieve the same user multiple times it gets the same string.

Comment: looks like an encoding problem?

Comment: ¿Did you found a way to decrypt these passwords from master2000.net?
I got the same output after some SQLi on their servers, so I dumped these passwords as HEX format, but still cann´t decode them.

Answer (score 2):

Try playing with character encoding options:

```
--charset=CHARSET
```

Answer (score 0):

This is no "charset" problem. You are dumping the binary password hash. You should use --binary-fields=pwdlogin (hidden option).